# What would happen if light was stored in a circular path?

Tags: visible-light, laser

This is like an idea for experiment.

Lets say one has an optical cable that makes a circle. There is a little Y junction/valve to the circle, through which one pumps some coherent light in. The length of circle is equal to some multiple of the wavelength of the light, as usual. One can go and create standing waves, interference patterns etc.

Now, I am curious what would happen to the light? Frame dragging, time dilation, passing of momentum via Poyinting vector etc.

- Would we be able to store more and more light inside the optical cable, without melting it?
- Once light is stored in circular path, can it be tapped into. Like you need a little bit of light and you just open the tap and shine it out.
- Would this create some other effects outside of the optical cable?

Comment: That's far too broad a question (it's really a whole range of questions). One of the common uses of such a system is a fiber-optic gyroscope: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibre_optic_gyroscope. Maybe you want to start with that and then specialize?

Comment: Nice, thanks. What is math saying? Can one cause frame dragging with a such setup?

Comment: I am not sure why you think that frame dragging is such a big deal. For one thing, as soon as the light is inside an optical medium, Lorentz invariance is broken and whatever one would observe is not frame dragging by definition. The other problem is that the angular momentum of light is not defined in such a trivial way, so I am not sure that one can talk about frame dragging by light even in the free space case naively.

Answer (score 0):

Energy cannot be stored in this way. Optical fibre will lose all the light energy in few seconds.
Optical fibre do not have 100% efficiency.
In case of 100% efficiency ,
No effect would be there due light energy in optical fibre outside.

Comment: Sure, but for the light, few seconds is enormous amount of time. As well, what would happen in a theoretically ideal case, when there are no losses. This is more of an educational question about physics, than engineering.

Comment: Or we can assume 100% efficiency.

Comment: Few seconds are enough for light to travel long distance. But what would you do by storing it for few seconds.

Comment: Yeah, we are learning physics here. What are the effects. Few seconds is huge for light.

Comment: If you consider 100% efficincy , yes you can store a large amount of energy and tap it out for few micro seconds.

Comment: Any optical cavity 'stores' optical energy - whether it is a circular path or not. The OP might also consider the whisper-gallery mode lasers. Build some gain in to your optical path and things get interesting.